# Sentence structure in English

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is this English sentence grammatically correct? What about its construction? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated:

Some people give to it the name that best represents for them the sensation.

Thank you

Comment: Some people give to it the name that for them best represents the sensation. Clunkiness reduced a tad.

Answer (score 0):

Some people give it the name, that for them, best represents the sensation. (clunkiness reduced again and commas separate the ideas)